# Read all resource files from App_LocalResources folder

Tags: c#, resources

I wanto to read all resource files from `App_LocalResources` folder

```
var resourceObject = new JObject();

            var resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Resources.ResourceFileName", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_LocalResources"));
            var resourceSet = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo(lang), true, true);

            var enumerator = resourceSet.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                resourceObject.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString(), enumerator.Value.ToString());
            }
```

But I get exception

```
Could not load file or assembly 'App_LocalResources' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"App_LocalResources
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Right now you are trying to load `App_LocalResources.dll`